# Printing letter by letter of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

On my homework, I am asked to print a string this way:

```
// string = 'zuckerberg'
// z
// zu
// zuc
// zuck
// zucke
// zucker
// zuckerb
// zuckerbe
// zuckerber
// zuckerberg
```

Is there a simple way to do it just using simple methods?
Couldn't find a good method so far.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Yes there is.  Can you show us how you attempted to solve this?  It can be done in only two lines of code.

Comment: Before asking others to help with your homework, please make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

Check it out, it works as you wanted.

```js
let data = 'zuckerberg';
let output = '';

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  output = output.concat(data[i]);
  console.log(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume your teacher is trying to teach you that a string is an array of characters. However, a bit code golf of me but wanted to share:

`string.split('').map((v,i,a) => console.log(data.slice(0, i+1)))`